# Is it possible to use custom fonts - using font-face?

Tags: javascript, css, windows-phone-7, font-face, webfonts

I'm able to embed and style a font-face in a webpage to view on Android and iPhone, and it works fine. However, it will not render on Windows Phone 7.5.

I've tried embedding the font into the CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family:'MyFont';
    src: url(data:font/woff;charset=utf-8;base64,d09GR...
}
```

...and also provided eot / ttf files, using a declaration that works across all other browsers -

```
@font-face {font-family:'MyFont';src:url('../fonts/MyFont-webfont.eot');src:url('../fonts/MyFont-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/MyFont-webfont.svg#MyFontRegular') format('svg'), url('../fonts/MyFont-webfont.woff')format('woff'), url('../fonts/MyFont-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;}
```

...but still no luck. I can't believe that the new Windows phones do not allow for font embedding, and only support a limited list of fonts, as mentioned in:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202920%28v=vs.92%29.aspx

Even if it's a Javascript rendering solution, any insight / hints or tips would be great...there must be some kind of workaround!

Comment: This seems like a bad idea on mobile due to the increase of bandwidth, processing, etc...

Comment: Yes, I agree. This will be a separate conversation if we can get it working.

Comment: Have you tried getting this working on the desktop IE9? If not, I'd start there.

Answer (score 6):

According to [this blog post](http://www.ubelly.com/2011/11/the-differences-between-ie9-on-the-desktop-and-ie9-on-wp7/) it's one of the "17 differences" between IE9 and IE9 on WP7.
And here's the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ff462082%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) which officially confirms it.

Answer (score 1):

I was successful in using [Cufón](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/) to display custom fonts on IE in WP 7.5. Typeface.js did NOT work.

Answer (score 0):

typeface.js works with it. Just tested it a few moments ago because I need to do the same thing. It uses canvas and vector drawings. http://typeface.neocracy.org/

Comment: Tried it right now on a WP7 (HTC HD7) and a WP7.5 (Nokia Lumia 800), typeface.js does not work for me.

Answer (score -7):

Whenever I need custom fonts I visit http://www.fontsquirrel.com/

It's an awesome site that lets you generate font-kits out of a .ttf file including a full CSS declaration with needed hacks for browser compatibility.

I don't know if it works on Win 7 Mobile, but I think it's worth a try

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but on testing the site on the Windows phone, no preview fonts seem to render. Think we need a specific workaround!

Comment: "a specific workaraound" - like android, firefox OS, openmoko or ubuntu phone ... maybe you can embed that :)