# @font-face not working in internet explorer mobile

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-phone-7, font-face

I've been building a website (http://www.hallometmirel.nl/troep/website) with a responsive layout and have been testing the various resolutions in several browsers and resolutions on my laptop and on my Galaxy S3.

Seeing as I can't get Internet Explorer on Google Play, I'm now testing the website on a Nokia Lumia 800 from work. It seems to be running Windows Phone 7.5, and since I can't find a button which displays which version of IE it is, and the smartphone being quite new, I suspect it's IE 9.

@font-face has been working so far in the latest version of Opera, Firefox, Chrome (desktop and mobile) and IE 9 (desktop).

I really have no idea why it wouldn't work in the mobile version, even if it's an older one, font-face is supported by older versions, right? I've tried tricking IE into showing the font by changing the .eot type or including a smileyface (apparently it does something). I can't find other topics with regards to the mobile version of IE.

This is the doc type, it might have something to do with IE9:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="nl-NL">
<head xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#">
```

And this is the way I embed the font:

```
@font-face {
font-family:'ChaletComprime-CologneEighty';
src:url('fonts/ChaletComprime-CologneEighty.eot');
src:url('fonts/ChaletComprime-CologneEighty.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('fonts/ChaletComprime-CologneEighty.woff') format('woff'),
        url('fonts/ChaletComprime-CologneEighty.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('fonts/ChaletComprime-CologneEighty.svg#svg/ChaletComprime-CologneEighty') format('svg')
}
```

And use it like this:

```
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{font-family:ChaletComprime-CologneEighty;color:#ef0f63;text-transform:uppercase}
```

Answer (score 10):

Hehe, WP has not full IE9. No font-face

Official (tm)(c)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ff462082%28v=vs.92%29.aspx

> Unsupported Features in Internet Explorer Mobile
>
> The following features are supported in the desktop version of Internet Explorer 9, and not in Internet Explorer Mobile.
>
> ...
>
> Downloadable fonts such as EOT, TTF/OTF and WOFF fonts
>
> ...

Else topics with current problem discussing

http://www.ubelly.com/2011/11/the-differences-between-ie9-on-the-desktop-and-ie9-on-wp7/

[Is it possible to use custom fonts - using font-face?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8789295/is-it-possible-to-use-custom-fonts-using-font-face)

http://www.anandtech.com/show/4351/windows-phone-75-mango-mobile-ie-9-browser-explored/2

Comment: Hmm. Might try using freaking javascript then. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

As a work-around, I was successful in using [Cufón](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/) to display custom fonts on IE in WP 7.5.