# Font Awesome Problems - Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, font-awesome

I've recently created a responsive web application using MVC 4 which utilises the awesomeness of font awesome. Everything is displaying fine when running the application locally, however after deploying the application and viewing it on my windows phone, the fonts appear as squares instead of the font images.

I've searched on google to find a reason for this and a solution, but I can't seem to find anything. I did find an article which said for me to add the following to the web config file in the WebServer section:

```xml
<staticContent>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
</staticContent>
```

However, this is not specific to Windows Phone and adding this section of code to the config file makes the image files disappear and they are no longer able to be found.

I'm just wondering if anyone else has experienced this issue, and if so, how they resolved it.

Comment: I see you used the windows-phone-7 tag but font-face is not supported on this platform (Windows Phone 8 only).

Comment: possible duplicate of [@font-face not working in internet explorer mobile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11522480/font-face-not-working-in-internet-explorer-mobile)

Comment: Thanks both, looks like it's just not supported. Nevermind!